# Retrieving principal components in R

Tags: r, pca

I am applying pca in R using the `prcomp` function. Calling `summary(mypca)` returs the importance of components (proportion of variance explained), but I couldn't find a way to retrieve these principal components. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for `$rotation`:

```
res <- prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE)
res$rotation

#                 PC1        PC2        PC3         PC4
# Murder   -0.5358995  0.4181809 -0.3412327  0.64922780
# Assault  -0.5831836  0.1879856 -0.2681484 -0.74340748
# UrbanPop -0.2781909 -0.8728062 -0.3780158  0.13387773
# Rape     -0.5434321 -0.1673186  0.8177779  0.08902432
```

Answer (score 2):

`str(mypca)` would point you to the `x` component

```
prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE)$x
                       PC1         PC2         PC3          PC4
Alabama        -0.97566045  1.12200121 -0.43980366  0.154696581
Alaska         -1.93053788  1.06242692  2.01950027 -0.434175454
Arizona        -1.74544285 -0.73845954  0.05423025 -0.826264240
Arkansas        0.13999894  1.10854226  0.11342217 -0.180973554
California     -2.49861285 -1.52742672  0.59254100 -0.338559240
Colorado       -1.49934074 -0.97762966  1.08400162  0.001450164
Connecticut     1.34499236 -1.07798362 -0.63679250 -0.117278736
Delaware       -0.04722981 -0.32208890 -0.71141032 -0.873113315
Florida        -2.98275967  0.03883425 -0.57103206 -0.095317042
```